# sending JSON object by needle

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to send a JSON object to a URL (provided) by somebody else. 
Here is the documentation provided by service side :

myProgram API :

Endpoint:  http://xxx.yyyy.com/yourCompany-service/rest/myProgram
This is a REST service exposed where you need to post a JSON with the following details. 
here is a sample of a JSON object you can send to the service:
Sample Request Json :

```
{
    "aa": "ertewer",
    "bb": 1,
    "cc": 10
}
```

Now my code:

```
var options = {
    host : 'http://xxx.yyyy.com/yourCompany-service/rest/myProgram',
    format : 'json',
    content_type: 'application/json'

} ;
var x = {
               "aa"       : "ABCD",
               "bb"        : 1,
               "cc"     : 10,
       }

needle.request('post', options.host, x, function(err, resp) {
           if (!err) {
               console.log(resp.body) ;
           }

           if (err) {
               console.log('neddle error');
           }
 }
```

but I always receive following message from server:

> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the request

Answer (score 4):

You need to say that you're going to send json to the request method. See the [options reference](https://github.com/tomas/needle#request-options)

```
needle.request('post', options.host, x, {json:true}, function(err, resp) {
           if (!err) {
               console.log(resp.body) ;
           }

           if (err) {
               console.log('neddle error');
           }
 }
```

Comment: Ambiguously, Tomas' JSON `needle.request` example doesn't use `json:true`; it uses `format:"json"` inside of the `data` object. (https://github.com/tomas/needle#needlerequestmethod-url-data-options-callback).

Comment: I used format: "json" and also json:true . Non of them works. Anybody have any solution using HTTP module of Node.js ? I remember it is possible but I don't find it anyware on the internet at the moment.

Comment: @CaseyFalk: The example is misleading, and is actually a get request where the format parameter is only used as a query parameter like so: ?format=json  
  
user3076730: In the question, you're not using format: json at all. You're only referring to options.host. If you do the request manually (using CURL, for example), does the server respond correctly?

Comment: @JohnSterling: *"The example is misleading"* -- Right-o, hence "ambiguously." Also, sending key-value pairs via a GET request ***is a way*** to send a JSON object. Just to amplify the Docs' unclarity. After this is figured out, perhaps it warrants a pull request...

Comment: @CaseyFalk: Yes, you are correct. Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: No problemo. : ) Happens with this sort of question. : )